# Is it possible to design a soil investigation borehole grid and apply this for location and attribute collection in the field with QGIS & QField?

Tags: qgis, qfield, borehole

I am very new to QGIS and GIS generally.

In the recent past I have worked with another company (ArcGIS users) with mobile phone based field app (Collector) to GPS locate position for pre-planned boreholes, logging the bore soil, i.e., depth below ground level, soil type classification, colour, moisture, etc, add a photo of bore/soil core.

Can the same be done using QGIS and QField?

Comment: Yes! And it is so much simpler than Collector... No licenses or cloud that complicates things. But Collector is easy to backup, just tap a button when you have an Internet Connection. In QField our users are copy pasting the geopackage where the data is stored to backup. But there might be a simpler way I dont know of...

Answer (score 2):

QGIS and QField are highly configurable tools that can be adjusted for many different possibilities. The attribute types you describe here normally fall into the currently available possibilities.

There are a number of [case studies](https://qfield.org/docs/en/case-studies/index.html) one of them [related to geology](https://qfield.org/docs/en/case-studies/geologic-mapping.html) in the QField documentation.

You can get inspired by them and follow up with more specific questions on one of the [support channels](https://qfield.org/docs/en/support/index.html).